# How to carry out a calculation in firebase storage reference observer?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am uploading multiple audiofiles of one story to firebase storage with the following code:

```
func uploadAudio(storyforUpload: 
Story, indexPath: IndexPath) {

    //set Firebase storage reference
    let uploadAudioRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("audiofiles")
    let storyItems = 
    storyforUpload.storyItems
    let totalItems = storyItems.count
    var itemCount = 0

    //Store audio to Fire Storage
        for item in storyItems {
          //Copy the audiofiles from local storage to firebase - This works no problem

            let taskRef = audioItemRef.putFile(from: localAudioFile, metadata: uploadAudioMetaData) { (downloadMetaData, err3) in
                if let err3 = err3 {
                    print("Error for audio upload is \(err3)")
                    return
                }
    // print("audio upload successful")
            }

            taskRef.observe(.progress) { (snapshot) in
                let pctThere = snapshot.progress!.fractionCompleted
                print("You are \(pctThere) complete")
            }

            taskRef.observe(.success) { (snapshot1) in
                print("Audio uploaded success \(snapshot1)")
                    itemCount = itemCount + 1
                    let status = itemCount / totalItems                  
       print("status is \(status)")

            }  
        }
}
```

In order to keep track of the status of the multiplefile upload I have created 'itemCount' and 'totalItems' and intend to change this into a percentage ('status') to display in a label in a cell in viewController. However, the status i.e. itemCount / totalItems does not calculate even though the itemCount is incrementing and the totalItems is set as expected. Typical output if printing the values is itemCount is '5', totalItems is '9', status is '0'. In fact, the status only displays '1' when it reaches the last item.

I have tried several things to resolve this:

- moved the calculation (itemCount / totalItems) into taskRef where - // print("audio upload successful") - is.
- moved the calculation into a separate function and called it from within the taskRef
- moved the calculation into the taskRef observer which is observing 'success' as show in displayed code above.
- In all above cases, tried to wrap the calculation and relevant display code(e.g. print((status)) in DispatchQueue.main.async.

All to no avail. Be grateful if anyone could tell me where I'm going wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've just realised my mistake. The 'itemCount' and 'totalItems' are both integers! So the result will only be an integer. Changing them to doubles resolves this...I am now slapping my own head.